Are the thermal frames being converted to RGB here?
I have some TIFF frames, and I attempted to calculate the temperature values to determine the respiration rate.
I am confused if the code correctly extracted the temperature values. Instead, it seems to have generated random values or automatically converted the frames to RGB or 8-bit grayscale.
The data source can be found at the following link: data source
The expected output should look like this: reference
After running the code, the output signal appears as shown here: output
import tifffile as tiff
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import argparse
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Construct argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", required=True, help="Path to input  directory containing TIFF files")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

input_dir = args["video"]
print("Input directory: " + input_dir)

def select_roi(image):
    """
    Allows user to select a region of interest (ROI) from the 16-bit image.
    """
    # Normalize 16-bit data for display without altering its original values
    normalized_image = cv2.normalize(image, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)
    color_map = cv2.applyColorMap(normalized_image, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
    cv2.imshow("Select Nose", color_map)
    bbox = cv2.selectROI("Select Nose", color_map, fromCenter=False, showCrosshair=True)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Print ROI coordinates
    x, y, w, h = bbox
    print(f"ROI's boundary is x1={x}, y1={y}, x2={x+w}, y2={y+h}")
    return bbox

# Open CSV file for writing results
csv_file = "nose_pixel_values.csv"
with open(csv_file, mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Frame", "Average Pixel Value"])  # CSV header

# Initialize ROI coordinates
x, y, w, h = None, None, None, None

# Loop through all TIFF files in the specified directory
for tiff_file in sorted(os.listdir(input_dir)):
    if tiff_file.endswith(".tiff"):
        file_path = os.path.join(input_dir, tiff_file)
        with tiff.TiffFile(file_path) as tif:
            gray16_frames = tif.asarray()
        print(f"Processing '{tiff_file}' with {len(gray16_frames)} frames.")

        # Get ROI from the first frame of the first TIFF file only
        if x is None:
            first_frame = gray16_frames[0]
            bbox = select_roi(first_frame)
            x, y, w, h = bbox

        for i, frame in enumerate(gray16_frames):
            # Extract the ROI based on the selected bbox
            roi = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

            # Calculate the average pixel value in the ROI (16-bit)
            avg_pixel_value = np.mean(roi)

            print(f"Frame {i}: Average pixel value : {avg_pixel_value}")
            print(f"Frame {i}: shape : {frame.shape}, data type : {frame.dtype}, min: {frame.min()}, max: {frame.max()}")

            # Write the result to the CSV file
            with open(csv_file, mode='a', newline='') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow([i, avg_pixel_value])

print(f"Finished processing all files.")


If you would like folk to help you, make it easy for them. You say you have a TIFF, but share a CSV? You say you want to use temperatures to determine a rate - how can that be? You seem to be processing all the images in a directory but is that necessary - can you show the problem with a single file? If not, please share all the necessary files. There seem to be quite a few pieces of information missing.

What is "data source". It looks fairly like "reference" to me. Where is a sample FLIR image and calibration scale?

The data used in this code (TIFF files) can be found in the "Boson" folder, while the CSV file serves as the reference input.

I might be wrong, but the pixel values of the .tiff files should represent temperature values, right?

Try printing frame.shape, frame.dtype,frame.min() and frame.max() for each frame.

values of the frame's shape, dtype, min and max

Have you looked at these files?  Each TIFF file contains 600 images, stored as individual pages.  You're only looking the first page.  Also, these files have extremely low contrast; your own data shows that the maximum and minimum values only differ by 0.3%.  You can't expect to extract meaningful data when the contrast is so low.  You can see (barely) that it's a person, but breath never shows up.

those are 16 bits. sure you can expect to get meaningful data out of them. just select an appropriate range out of the full 16 bits, and stretch that onto a black-to-white color map.

see, this is the first frame in the first file, range-stretched. looks fine to me. https://i.sstatic.net/TMw4vapJ.png

this is a video of the first file. contrast stretched per file, not per frame. you can see the temperature of the nostrils changing. https://imgur.com/a/0sBdiux

Understood! Thank you

Is your code supposed to process the 600 frames in a single TIFF? Or all the frames in all the TIFFs?

All the frames of all the TIFF.
